# C++, How to use maps for holding multiple integer values

Tags: c++, maps, key-value

I'm working on a word Tagging system for a C++ project.  I need a system where a map stores the following key-value information:

```
word["with"] = 16, 6, 15;
```

Where ["with"] is the index, and the 3-tuple (16, 6, 15) are values of the index.  I've tried maps, but I keep getting semantic errors, which I understand are a result of not being able to give a key more then 1 value.

I tried multi maps, but I can't seem to get the syntax to suit my needs?

I would like to refrain from using Structs or Classes, as this database already contains 200 words, and I'm trying to keep my lines of code readable and too a minimum.

How would I go about this?  Am I missing something? How would you declare a system like this?

Comment: std::multi_map or std::unordered_map should work for you, can you please share your code?

Comment: map<string, <vector<int> >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a map that maps `Strings` to `Vectors` or some other data structure that can hold an arbitrary number of integers.

Worth noting, however, that things like Structs and Classes are components of a language meant to organize code. Structs group related data; classes model groups of related data and their associated behaviors. It's certainly possible to do everything without them but that would make for some very unreadable code.

The number of lines and whether or not you use classes/structs are poor metrics for the complexity and readability of your code. And the modularity they offer far exceeds the minute runtime cost of dereferencing those values.

Comment: Thanks, very informative. I should add that the program is already at 500 lines, I'm expecting it to be 1,500 before the end of the week. My current networking approach that I've devised for the system, HIVE, relies on making sure the program is as small and runs as fast as possible. But thank you for your answer, I'll certainly reconsider Structs. I'm not afraid of Classes and Structs, I already am using them in the program.

Comment: @AdamShort do not confuse small with fast. Sometimes bigger is better, and if you are developing a system as opposed to performance tuning it, start with simple. Where simple and fast cross, go with fast, but when fast is a confusing mess, go with simple until it's proven that you need the extra speed. Easier to debug means less bugs when you get to tuning the system.

Comment: @user4581301 thanks man thats some good advice, this is my first time programming in C++, and also my first tackling a project this big so thank you for the helpful advice. I'll keep that in mind as I move through!

Answer (score 2):

You should declare your map as `std::map<std::string, std::vector<unsigned int>>`, so you can have a vector of values for your index.

Comment: @AdamShort I wanted to explain *something* since none of the "with comment" delete reasons fit ...

Comment: @o11c An answer being short (or even inferior) is not a good reason to delete it, unless there are already 10+ answers.  Shorter isn't even a good reason to downvote, let alone delete!  Brevity is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`word["with"] = 16, 6, 15;`//This usage is wrong

`std::multimap` or `std::unordered_multimap` should work for you.

If you define word as follows:

```
std::multimap<std::string,int> word;
```

You should insert values to map as shown below:

```
std::string key="with";

word.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(key,16));
word.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(key,6));
word.insert(std::pair<std::string,int>(key,15));


for( auto &x : word)
  std::cout<<x.first<<" " << x.second<<"\n";
```

As user4581301 pointed out in comment if you have C++11 enabled compiler, you can insert values into `std::multimap` as follows:

```
    word.emplace("with",16);
    word.emplace("with",6);
    word.emplace("with",15);
```

Demo: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7ede5c497172c5d

Comment: Yes, but I need 3 values, not one.

Comment: @AdamShort now there are 3 values with key as "with"

Answer (score 0):

**Example for using C++ maps to hold multiple integer values:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    std::map<int, std::vector<int> > mymap2;
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    myvector.push_back(8);
    myvector.push_back(11);
    myvector.push_back(53);
    mymap2[5] = myvector;
    cout << mymap2[5][0] << endl;
    cout << mymap2[5][1] << endl;
    cout << mymap2[5][2] << endl;
}
```

Prints:

```
8
11
53
```

Just replace the int datatypes with a string and you should be able to map strings to lists of numbers.